# How do disable user list on login screen? (Prompt for username and password) Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: login, password, login-screen

I was curious as to if there is a way to disable the user list on the login screen on Ubuntu 15.10, thus making it so that any user would have to enter their **username as well as their password** to log in.

I have already modified /etc/lightdm/users.conf by adding...

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true    
greeter-hide-users=true    
allow-guest=false
```

... and restarting the computer, but I am only prompted for my password, and my user name is already selected. With that, I also have the ability to use a guest session, even though that shouldn't be allowed with the code above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a folder in the `/etc/lightdm/` folder called `lightdm.conf.d`:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
```

Next, create a file and call it `10-ubuntu.conf`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf
```

and add the following lines to it:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true    
greeter-hide-users=true    
allow-guest=false
```

**For 16.04 or newer:**

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true    
greeter-hide-users=true    
allow-guest=false
```

Change the line `user-session=` to whatever desktop you are using, like if you are using Xubuntu, change it to `user-session=xubuntu`.

After these lines are added, reboot host, and you should see login instead of the user list:

[image]

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM shows information about LightDM and that the file `user.conf` can be ignored if `accountservice` is running on the host.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That file doesn't exist in Ubuntu 15.10. The only file or directory under /etc/lightdm/ is users.conf, given by ls. It might be because I have a different distro than you do.

Comment: @MattCiolkosz I am going to set up a 15.10 installation and try it out really fast to see if it will take any configuration files in that folder to do it.

Comment: @MattCiolkosz Unfortunately I cannot get 15.10 to install in a VM for me right now.  I am running 14.04 anyway.  You could create a file like the one I have listed and see if that helps.  According to the lightdm link I put in my answer, you can have a file with that information in it.

Comment: @MattCiolkosz Edited answer, and I was able to create it in Ubuntu 15.10 and it works great.  =)