# How do I disable the guest user without lightdm?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, guest-session

In versions of ubuntu above 16.04 the default display manager is gdm3. I am attempting to remove the guest user from an ubuntu VM but I don't know how to do it without lightdm. How do I do this? I have tried switching to lightdm but I cannot find the lighdm.conf file, only the lightdm.conf.d file, and it is completely blank. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can still create the file needed to turn that off.  I wrote something similar a while ago, but still holds true:  https://askubuntu.com/a/731455/231142