# Changing Login Screen from List to Manual Entry?

Tags: login-screen

Is it possible to change the login screen so that instead of clicking on your username you have to type it in?

I did ask ChatGPT this and the first time the answer it gave me seemed to work but every other time it suggested I use another display manager and I ended up bricking my install.

Comment: Which distro and version of Ubuntu/Linux are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do disable user list on login screen? (Prompt for username and password) Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731425/how-do-disable-user-list-on-login-screen-prompt-for-username-and-password-ubu)

Comment: Also see [How to Hide All The User Accounts in Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04 Login Screen](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/hide-user-accounts-ubuntu-20-04-login-screen/),

Comment: Yes easily, but how you do that will vary on what you're actually using, which you've not actually mentioned. The DM acts as greeter, and your installation media & what packages you install (post-install) and your answers can dictate which DM is in control, but you've provided no specifics.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support